# Where can i download .NET MVC 2.0 runtime?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller, asp.net-mvc-2

I am looking for MVC 2.0 runtime for .NET.
Anybody have the link?

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

You can

- [Download ASP.NET MVC 2 using the Microsoft Web Platform Installer](http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=185037)

or

- [Download ASP.NET MVC 2 from the Download Center](http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=157074)

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking for the source?  You can download it here: http://aspnet.codeplex.com/releases/view/41742

HTH.